# Unable to show bars for BarChart

Tags: objective-c, ios-charts

@daniel.gindi  I am able to draw the charts but only values are displaying no bars.Can you please help me out.

```
set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals label:@"Energy Values (KWh)"];
[set1 setColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataSets addObject:set1];

BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];
[data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.f]];

data.barWidth = 0.9f;

self.barChartView.data = data;
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: i m using xcode7.3 if i run theri sample demo, it shows many errors, it is possible to use this library in xcode 7.3, please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong formatter for x-axis. The x-axis value should be in day of year format.